# How to get birthday list from facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm developing an application and I want to show a friends birthday. Is this possible?
 How can I get a friends birth date from facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask for the permission like:-

Define Macro in your .h file like:-

```
#define kFBPermission @"@\"offline_access\", @\"publish_stream\",@\"friend_birthday\",@\"user_events\",@\"read_stream\",@\"friends_likes\""
```

Now in .h file write.objDelegate is object of AppDelegate class.

```
if (![objDelegate.facebook isSessionValid])
    {
    [objDelegate.facebook authorize:App_ID permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access",@"publish_stream",@"friends_birthday",@"user_events",@"read_stream",@"friends_likes", nil] delegate:self];
    }
```

To show birthday in a label use:-

```
[lblDOB setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.friendDictionary valueForKey:@"birthday"]]];
```

Hope it helps.Thanks :)

Comment: its not working can u please explain  in brief

Comment: You have an error in your permission list: it's "friends_birthday" (with a 's'). A wrong permission make the fb app not working.

Answer (score 0):

By default, most object properties are returned when you make a query. You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the "fields" query parameter. For example, this URL will only return the id, name, and picture of Ben: https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=id,name,picture

You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in the same response.

The "ids" query parameter also accepts URLs. This is useful for finding IDs of URLs in the Open Graph. For example: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

Additionally, there is a special identifier me which refers to the current user. So the URL https://graph.facebook.com/me returns the active user's profile.

When retrieving Posts via the /home, /feed, or /posts connection, you can restrict the results to only those with a location attached by adding with=location to the URL parameters:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?with=location

Answer (score 0):

to get freinds birthdate from Facebook account use Facebook connect.

here is code you have to fire query like below to get the friends info.

```
    - (IBAction)getFriends {

        [self initFacebook];

        if ([facebook isSessionValid]) {

            [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,name,gender,picture,birthday" andDelegate:self]; 

            } else {

            [self loginToFacebook];

            }
         }
```